# Do not display object data in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm doing a site in Rails 5 and I have a problem in a method that does a search of articles in the database, I have no problem in showing the data I want as the reference for the article, title or description, but I do not want to display the data of the object that the driver creates as shown in the image:

[image]

My controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token #Para usar metodo post
  before_action :authenticate_usuario!, except: [:index,:show,:miperfil,:inicio]

  def search
    respond_to do |format| 
      if params[:busqueda].strip != "" #si hay solo espacios no busca nada
        @busqueda = params[:busqueda]
        puts "\nIngreso al metodo de búsqueda..."
        @rposts = Post.where("titulo like ?", "%#{@busqueda.downcase}%").order(created_at: :desc)
        format.html { render :busqueda }
      else
        format.html { render :inicio, success: 'Por favor ingresa una palabara para la búsqueda.' }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And my view:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2>Resultados para <i style="color: wheat;">"<%= @busqueda %>"</i></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <br>
        <h4 class="h4class" style="color: wheat">Articulos encontrados: <%= @rposts.size %></h4>
        <% if @rposts.size > 0 %>
            <%= @rposts.each do |post|  %>
                <%= link_to post do %>
                    <h5><%= post.titulo %>.</h5>
                <% end %>

                <p><small><%= content_with_emoji(truncate(post.contenido.html_safe, :length => 250)) %></small></p>
                <% if (post.contenido.length > 250) %>
                  <%= link_to "Ver más", post%>
                <% end %>
                <hr>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `=` from the `each` iterator you're applying over your `@rposts` variable:

```
<% @rposts.each do |post|  %>
  ...
<% end %>
```